# How to check if the font has a symbol

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I have the following css rule in my document

```
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Tahoma;
```

but I found out that some browsers have Trebuchet MS font
without symbols I need (some language with non-latin characters).
And in this case browser shows squares instead of symbols.

How can I check it (probably via javascript)?
(i.e. how can I check if some symbols are missing in the
font installed in my visitor's browser)

Comment: why not try checking if the visitor has the named font? before trying to check if that font actually has the characters in it that you require.

Comment: if my visitor hasn't got such a font (Trebuchet MS) browser uses second font (Tahoma) and everything is ok, but if my user do have Trebuchet MS but without needed symbols then squares displayed

Comment: This is answered here by using canvas to render the glyph (I havent marked it as duplicate because the other answer isn't great): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639734/detect-what-unicode-glyphs-exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't check individual symbols, but you can check the encoding.

Comment: encoding is ok, and I'm sure about it

Answer (score 5):

On Windows you may be able to detect from JavaScript which characters are missing from a font by:

a) creating a designer detector font that contains a very wide [notdef character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/typography/opentype/spec/recom#glyph-0-the-notdef-glyph) of say 100pt wide. The detector font needs to be a proportional font, constructed similar to the [Adobe notdef](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/adobe-notdef) font `AND-Regular.otf`. ([this link](https://blogs.adobe.com/CCJKType/2012/01/extreme-otf.html) may be relevant too?).

b) Use the detector font as the fallback font (here I am using `adobe notdef` as the detector font) e.g.

```
    <div style="font-family: sans-serif, Segoe UI symbol, adobe notdef">
       &#xFFFD;test&#x25a1;&#x25AF;&#x1F618;&#x1F605;
       &#x1F617;&#x1F60E;&#x1F60E;&#x1F30A;&#x1F30A;&#x1F600;
    </div>
```

Now you can test a single unicode character by putting it into a div with `display: inline-block` to force minimum width.

If the glyph is not in the list of fonts, then the notdef glyph from the last font will be used, which will be 100pt wide, which can be detected in javascript from the offsetWidth of the div.

I explored the idea enough to validate that it is very likely to work, but I didn't have enough time to actually make working code, sorry!

I would expect the technique to work on other operating systems too (unless browsers render the `.notdef` character in another font!).

Alternatively, you could use a zero width font like [Adobe blank](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/adobe-blank/) which has a zero width `.notdef` character 0 (the `AdobeBlank.otf` file is only 20kb). This could detect missing glyphs, because the div containing a missing glyph will end up with an offsetWidth == 0. However I think it would be a less reliable technique than using a very wide glyph, because there are valid glyphs with zero width so it woudl get false positives for valid zero width glyphs (particularly `U+200B` and maybe other control characters?).

Answer (score 2):

Correctly behaving browsers pick up glyphs from the secondary font if the primary font lacks a glyph for a character. But browsers, especially IE, are known to get this wrong relatively often.

The best approach is to include a font in the `font-family` list only if the font is known to contain all the characters that may appear in the element content. Although fonts exist as different versions under the same name, we can usually find out sufficiently reliably whether a font contains some given characters.

For a small piece of text, you could copy the text into Notepad, set the font Trebuchet MS, and check out that everything is OK. (Notepad is good here because it does not do font substitutions.)

Comment: this issue appears only with several percent of my visitors and always in Chrome

Comment: So what is the issue? Which character(s), under which CSS settings? URL?

Comment: the issue that is described above - no cyrillic characters in Trebuchet MS font

Comment: I see, it seems that some old versions of Trebuchet MS indeed lack Cyrillic characters. But I don’t think there’s a way to detect that in JavaScript. And when I tested with Hebrew letters (which are not included even in the modern version of Trebuchet MS), Chrome handled this just fine: `<div style="font-family: Trebuchet MS, Tahoma">א</div>` displays the alef in Tahoma, by the specifications. Some old versions of Chrome may get this wrong. In any case, if there is a chance that a font does not contain all the characters you need, just use a different font.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela You say that with such nonchalance, as though it is nothing to just use another font! Oh, but it is a dagger in the heart of a designer when his font is so carefully chosen, paired and balanced with the rest of his design, white space perfectly calculated, colors handpicked to reflect the mood evoked by the natural color of his typeface of choice, only to be forced by technological limitations to discard it all and restructure around an entirely different font! Show some respect, man! (</melodrama>)