# Detect what Unicode glyphs exist?

Tags: javascript, encoding, web

Is there a way in JavaScript/CSS/web stuff to detect whether the system has a valid glyph for a certain Unicode character?

For example, I would like to detect whether a certain character in a language shows up as a square box because the user doesn't have a font that shows those Unicode points, or if they will actually be seeing the characters.

Comment: There's no way to know how extended chars will be rendered if you don't control the font that is used.  You *can*, however, provide a font via [web-fonts](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-webfonts/), thus ensuring that glyphs exist for the portions of the unicode set you want to display.

Comment: You mean, in a certain font face? System does not have glyphs, font faces do.

Comment: @Lee what if you tried to read the screen pixels?

Comment: @Lee note that only missing API prevents that, not a technical difficulty or security barrier.

Comment: @JanDvorak post an answer if you have a ready solution.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: The problem is that the "square box" placeholder for unknown unicode glyphs is not standardized. I already saw, for example, font renderers which replaced it with an opaque box with the unicode codepoint in hex written on it.

Comment: You could find/create a font that _definitely_ works, then try to render in the tested font, then in the font family consisting of both.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution described here: [Detecting missing character glyphs, and Firefox's little boxes with hex codepoints inside them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60607384/detecting-missing-character-glyphs-and-firefoxs-little-boxes-with-hex-codepoin)

Basically, paint the glyph to a canvas as an oblique (normal) character, paint to another canvas as italic. then compare pixel by pixel. If they are identical, then the glyph is not available in the font.