# Detecting missing character glyphs, and Firefox's little boxes with hex codepoints inside them

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, fonts, rendering

I want to be able to test if a specific character, such as  (that's a raindrop emoji, in case you can't see it), will render correctly in a user's web browser, so that if that character doesn't render I can use an alternate.

The following code does the trick in Chrome:

```js
export function doesCharacterGlyphExist(elementOrFont: Element | string, charOrCodePoint: string | number): boolean {
  if (typeof charOrCodePoint === 'number')
    charOrCodePoint = String.fromCodePoint(charOrCodePoint);

  const metrics = getFontMetrics(elementOrFont);
  const PADDING = 8;
  const size = metrics.lineHeight + PADDING;

  const canvas0 = (doesCharacterGlyphExist as any).canvas0 || ((doesCharacterGlyphExist as any).canvas0 =
                  document.createElement('canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement);
  const canvas1 = (doesCharacterGlyphExist as any).canvas1 || ((doesCharacterGlyphExist as any).canvas1 =
                  document.createElement('canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement);
  const canvases = [canvas0, canvas1];
  const pixmaps = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    const canvas = canvases[i];

    canvas.width = size;
    canvas.height = size;
    canvas.style.opacity = '1';

    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.fillStyle = 'white';
    context.fillRect(-1, -1, size + 2, size + 2);
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.font = metrics.font;
    // Compare pixels for test character to pixels for known character without a glyph
    context.fillText(i === 0 ? charOrCodePoint : '\uFFFE', 0, metrics.ascent);

    pixmaps[i] = context.getImageData(0, 0, size, size).data;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < pixmaps[0].length; ++i) {
    if (pixmaps[0][i] !== pixmaps[1][i])
      return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

The basic idea is to draw a character to a canvas and see if it renders the same pixels, or different pixels, than a known non-existent glyph, which typically renders as an empty box.

Firefox, however, oh-so-helpfully renders each unknown character as an individually-distinguishable little box with a hexadecimal Unicode codepoint value inside.

[image]

While normally this is very helpful, in this particular case, it's a big problem.

Does any know how to turn off this feature of Firefox? I've searched for Firefox-specific CSS features, but I've come up empty.

Or, if not that, can anyone suggest a totally different approach than my canvas-comparison trick to determine which character codepoints have genuine glyphs, and which do not?

Comment: What is the getFontMetrics function?

Answer (score 0):

While I'm still be open for a better answer, at least I've got a workaround for now.

As it turns out, the little box shown for a missing glyph (whether it's a simple empty box or the Firefox variant with a hex codepoint inside) is unaffected by CSS italics. Real, rendered characters however are changed by italics. So if a normal character is the same as its italic variant, it's not a real character.

I prefer the test I'm using for Chrome, however, so I'm only using this alternate test for Firefox.

```js
function changeItalic(font: string): string {
  if (/\b(italic|oblique)\b/.test(font))
    return font.replace(/\b(italic|oblique)\b/, '');
  else
    return 'italic ' + font;
}

export function doesCharacterGlyphExist(elementOrFont: Element | string, charOrCodePoint: string | number): boolean {
  if (typeof charOrCodePoint === 'number')
    charOrCodePoint = String.fromCodePoint(charOrCodePoint);

  const metrics = getFontMetrics(elementOrFont);
  const PADDING = 8;
  const size = metrics.lineHeight + PADDING;

  const canvas0 = (doesCharacterGlyphExist as any).canvas0 || ((doesCharacterGlyphExist as any).canvas0 =
                  document.createElement('canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement);
  const canvas1 = (doesCharacterGlyphExist as any).canvas1 || ((doesCharacterGlyphExist as any).canvas1 =
                  document.createElement('canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement);
  const canvases = [canvas0, canvas1];
  const pixmaps = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    const canvas = canvases[i];

    canvas.width = size;
    canvas.height = size;
    canvas.style.opacity = '1';

    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.fillStyle = 'white';
    context.fillRect(-1, -1, size + 2, size + 2);
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    // Compare pixels for test character to pixels for known character without a glyph.
    // For Firefox, which renders missing glyphs all differently, check if a character
    // looks the same as itself when rendered in italics -- the missing glyph boxes
    // remain straight when italicized.
    context.font = (i === 1 && isFirefox() ? changeItalic(metrics.font) : metrics.font);
    context.fillText(i === 0 || isFirefox() ? charOrCodePoint : '\uFFFE', 0, metrics.ascent);

    pixmaps[i] = context.getImageData(0, 0, size, size).data;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < pixmaps[0].length; ++i) {
    if (pixmaps[0][i] !== pixmaps[1][i])
      return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```